# Cannot effectively add class to namespace in Roslyn

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am using Roslyn 2.0 and the `SyntaxFactory` to generate a `SyntaxTree`:

```
var namespaceNode = SyntaxFactory.NamespaceDeclaration(
    SyntaxFactory.ParseName("Root.MyNamespace1"));
var classNode = SyntaxFactory.ClassDeclaration("MyClass");

namespaceNode.AddMembers(classNode);
```

#### Missing member

Seems all ok, but when I inspect in the debugger object `namespaceNode` by calling `namespaceNode.ToString()`, I get:

```
namespaceRoot.MyNamespace1{}
```

Everytime I use `ToString` on a `SyntaxNode` it usually emits the printed code, so I am pretty sure that the problem here is that the namespace is empty. The class is not there, even though I called `AddMembers`.

The namespace has no member in it! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I write this:

```
namespaceNode.AddMembers(classNode);
```

I receive a warning in my Visual Studio 2017 Community that explains what is happening:

> RS1014    'NamespaceDeclarationSyntax' is immutable and 'AddMembers' will not have any effect on it. Consider using the return value from 'AddMembers'.

So you have to

```
namespaceNode = namespaceNode.AddMembers(classNode);
```

Comment: Oh dammit that makes so much sense... Of course it is immutable, thanks! I feel so stupid

Comment: I don't get that warning. Do you have some analyzer or extension installed, which is producing it?

Comment: @svick I've got a new C# project created in VS 2017, and I had added the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Analyzers analyzer ([this nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/))

Comment: @xanatos I believe I have found the reason why the analyzer warning didn't show up for me and [reported it](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/1128).